# Removing one array from another array, using this particular code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following array, which holds other arrays (they are in fact coordinates of a html5 canvas).

```
var crossesPos = [[317, 193], [110, 334], [390, 347], [281, 222], [307, 384], [329, 366], [230, 104], [276, 156], [173, 330], [227, 100], [397, 261], [341, 389], [233, 223], [261, 350], [267, 286]]
```

Lest say:

```
x = 317;
y = 193;
```

**In the following function, how can I remove the array [317,193] from crossesPos?**

```
function checkForCrosses(x,y){
    var position;
    jQuery.each(crossesPos, function(){
        position = this;
        if(x == position[0] && y == position[1]){
            // how do I remove the array [317,193] from crossesPos?
        }
    });
}
```

Ty!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following code to splice the exact coordinates from the array. Put this code in your function. This is more efficient than JQuery code.

### Pure JavaScript

```
for(var i=0; i<crossesPos.length; i++)
{
    if(crossesPos[i][0] === x)
        if(crossesPos[i][1] === y)
        {
            crossesPos.splice(i,1);
            break;
        }
}
```

---

**Important note:** If you want to delete **all** the matching elements within the array (and not only **one**), you must edit the code, deleting the `break;` condition and **inverting the loop**:

```
for(var i=crossesPos.length-1; i>=0; i--)
{
     if(crossesPos[i][0] === x)
        if(crossesPos[i][1] === y) crossesPos.splice(i,1);          
}
```

---

### [Working demo (with sexy output)](http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/sde3d/)

---

### [Performance comparison (test it yourself!)](http://jsperf.com/array-splicing-pure-vs-jquery)

This is (at the time of this post) the most efficient and performant way to execute your needs, since the closest results are still **~90% slower than my answer**.

[image: Performance comparison]

Comment: What's wrong with my answer?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but I *suspect* it's to do with `for .. in` which (at least in my experience) is discouraged.

Comment: @cdhowie You are right. I just realized the `for ... in` causes a huge performance impact!

Comment: Since you have removed that I can now upvote with a clear conscience. :)

Comment: @cdhowie I also included a performance comparison. This was actualy slowing performances of the script by **98%** over my old `for ... in`.

Comment: Yup, grep is not fast.  Only reason I chose that is because it's a solution baked in to jQuery and is easy to understand.  But for performance you can't beat `array.splice()`.

Comment: Why did you add the `break;`?

Comment: @Ian Thank you for the question, it reminded me I forgot to add a comment at this part of the code: the `break;` can be removed if you want to remove all the matching elements. If you do so, you also need to **invert the loop** so that `i == crossesPos.length; i>=0; i--` otherwise splicing will affect the index positions of your array elements.

Answer (score 3):

The "jQuery way" to do this would be to use [`jQuery.grep()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/):

```
var crossesPos = [[317, 193], [110, 334], [390, 347], [281, 222], [307, 384],
                  [329, 366], [230, 104], [276, 156], [173, 330], [227, 100],
                  [397, 261], [341, 389], [233, 223], [261, 350], [267, 286]];

crossesPos = jQuery.grep(crossesPos,
                         function(e) { return e[0] === 317 && e[1] === 193; },
                         true);
```

[(See it run)](http://jsfiddle.net/tKj9r/1/)

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain their vote?  This code is tested and working.

Comment: It seems like someone's spamming downvotes for no reasons. I did not actualy know about `$.grep()`, so thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

Use jQuery's **[grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/)** utility function:

```
var x = 317,
    y = 193,
    newPos = $.grep(crossesPos, function(n, i){
          return (n[0] != x || n[1] != y);
    });
```

Comment: The test should be `(n[0] != x || n[1] != y)`.

Comment: Read again - the ask is to remove the array `[317, 193]`.

Comment: Yes, and this code would also remove `[317, 0]` and `[0, 193]`.

Comment: Err, I think you're confused. It does not return if x is 317 and y is 193 in the same array i.e. [317, 193]. It will return for everything else, which is what is required.

Comment: Awww...why the down vote?

Comment: For `[317, 0]` the condition is `(317 != 317 && 0 != 193)` which is `(true && false)` which is `false`, which means that `[317, 0]` would be incorrectly removed.  The function must return `false` *only* for `[317, 193]`.  This is why you want `||` instead of `&&`.

Comment: @cdhowie - You're absolutely correct! Sorry, my bad! Bad bad robot - no doughnut!

Comment: FWIW, it's generally easier to negate the whole thing than try to distribute the negation through the condition.  Example: `!(n[0] == x && n[1] == y)` (distributing the negation means flipping `==` to `!=` *and* `&&` to `||`).  Or you can use the third "invert" argument to `grep()` as I chose to do in my answer.  All are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the .splice() function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

```
crossesPos.splice(index,1);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use splice() to delete the item found. [This](http://plnkr.co/edit/BEx1lUFqssKvG3kJgasU?p=preview) is a working plunk. Open up your console to see the modified array.

Code to add to your function:

```
function checkForCrosses(x, y){
    var position,
        length = crossesPos.length;

    for (var i = length; i > 0; i--) {
      position = crossesPos[i - 1];

      if (x == position[0] && y == position[1])
        crossesPos.splice(i - 1, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this works, it doesn't do what you expect. The .each() loop iterates over the original array's length. Modifying it as you iterate doesn't change that, so the loop iterates over indexes that don't exist anymore. And since you're encouraging the use of this instead of the second parameter of the callback, you're checking window's properties. If you're going to remove elements (instead of returning a new array of the accepted elements), you should use a normal for/while loop and iterate backwards

Comment: Ahh, oops, you're right, a for/while loop in reverse will do the trick.

Comment: Plunk updated to use for loop in reverse.

Answer (score 1):

http://underscorejs.org or http://lodash.com can make this hugely easier, but if you insiste on doing it straight:

```
var pos = -1;
jQuery.each(crossesPos,function(idx,item) {
  if (x===item[0] && y===item[1]) {
    pos = idx;
  }
});
crossesPos.splice(idx,1);
```

Or more simply

```
var ary = [];
jQuery.each(crossesPos,function(idx,item) {
  if (x!==item[0] || y!==item[1]) {
    ary.push(item);
  }
});
crossesPos = ary;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `filter`

```
function checkForCrosses(x,y){
    function myFilter(element, index, array) {
        return (element[0] != x || element[1] != y);
    }
    crossesPos = crossesPos.filter(myFilter);
}
```

Then `crossesPos` holds the array without `[317, 193]`

Comment: Your condition isn't right, someone already pointed out it should be `element[0] != x || element[1] != y` if you're going to use the "not equals" approach

Comment: This code would also remove `[317, 0]` and `[0, 193]` if they were in `crossesPos`.

Comment: Oh yes that's right, I need to review my boolean algebra :)

Answer (score 1):

```
//
//
//  here's some common Array operations you might find usefull and familiar: 
//   
// .each( callback, boolFlgFromLast )
//   # iterate an array runing given callback-fn for every array item, 
//   # pass it curent array key and value, respectively, 
//   # set context of the callback to host array, 
//   # if boolFlgFromLast argument is ( === )true, iterate from last element, 
//   # break iteration if callback returns ( === )false, 
//   # return iterated array
//
// .not( callback ) 
//   # remove items for which callback returns ( === )true
//   # keep others
//   # return host array
//  
// .keep( callback )
//   # keep items for which callback returns ( === )true
//   # remove others
//   # return host array
//
// .desparse()
//   # 'desparse' host array in place
//   # return host array
// 
//
//    var
//       a = [ 
//               [317, 193], 
//               [110, 334], 
//               [390, 347], 
//            ];
//    
//  
//    a
//     .each( function ( k, v ) { console.log('['+ k +'] -> '+ v ); } )
//     .not(  function ( k, v ) { console.log(' * '); return ( v[0] == 317 ) && ( v[1] == 193 ); } )
//     .each( function ( k, v ) { console.log('['+ k +'] -> '+ v ); } )
//     .keep( function ( k, v ) { console.log(' * '); return Math.random() > .1; } )
//     .each( function ( k, v ) { console.log('['+ k +'] -> '+ v + ', [ this === a ] -> '+ ( this === a )  ); } );
//       
//     // make sparse array
//     a[5] = [0,0];
//     console.log('sparse array: ', a);
//     
//     a
//     .desparse()
//     .each( function ( k, v ) { console.log('['+ k +'] -> '+ v ); } )
//       
//
//
;( function( _a ) { 

    var
        t  = !0, 
        f  = !t;

    _a.each = function ( fn ) { 

                    var
                       len = this.length, 
                       i   = 0;

                    for( ; i < len ; i++ ) { 
                       if ( fn.call( this, i, this[i] ) === f ) break;
                    }

                    return this;

    };

    overload( 'each', _a, function ( fn, flgIterateBackwards ) {

                              if ( flgIterateBackwards === t ) {

                                  var
                                     i = this.length - 1;

                                   for ( ; i >= 0 ; i-- ) { 
                                       if ( fn.call( this, i, this[i] ) === f ) break;
                                   }

                                   return this;

                              } else {

                                  return this.each( fn );

                              }
                          } 
            );

    _a.not = function ( callback ) { 
                  return this.each( function ( k, v ) { 
                                      ( callback.call( this, k, v ) === t ) && this.splice( k, 1 );
                                    }, t );
             };

    _a.keep = function ( callback ) { 
                  return this.each( function ( k, v ) { 
                                       ( callback.call( this, k, v ) === t ) || this.splice( k, 1 );
                                    }, t );
              };


    _a.desparse = function () { 
        return this.not( function ( k, v ) { return k in this === f; } );
    };


    // helper fn-s

    function overload ( fn, obj,  newfn ) { 

       return ( function ( origfn ) { 

            obj[fn] = function () {

                        var
                            args = _a.slice.call( arguments );

                        if ( newfn.length == arguments.length ) {

                            return newfn.apply( this, args )

                        } else if ( isfn ( origfn ) ) {

                            return origfn.apply( this, args )

                        } else {
                            // ignore non method props
                        }

                      };

        } )( obj[fn] );
     }  

    function isfn ( o ) { 
       return ( typeof o === 'function' ) && 
              ( Object.prototype.toString.call( o ) === '[object Function]' );
    }


} )( Array.prototype );

//
```